# What actually happens when this type of condition in the for loop is checked?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

I can't understand the difference between the condition checked in a `for` loop and an `if` condition. Do both behave in a different way?

When I write:

```
int num = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < 15 && num; i++){
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

It only checks whether `i < 15` and it doesn't check for `i < num` and prints all the way from 0 to 14.

But at the same time, if I write a `if` condition like:

```
if(x < 15 && num)
```

It checks for both `x < 15` and `x < num`.

Comment: "*it checks for both x<15 and x<num.*" Why do you think that? Can you show code proving that this is the case?

Comment: Yes, sure..
If we consider x = 12 

in the if statement it is checking for both the conditions x<15 (true) and x <num(false)

and finally returning false.

Comment: but in the case of for loop, it is just checking for first condition

though value of i goes above num value.. it goes on checking till the first condition gets false.

Comment: You should add i to both conditions , in this case the condition is **continue till i is lower than 15 and num is true ** and the num is true allways , but if you want it that way you should add i to second condition ``i < 15 && i < num ``.

Comment: A C++ compiler is not a natural language processor. Not the compiler will speak our language, but we have to speak the compiler's language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition of a loop (whether a `for` loop, a `while` loop, or a `do..while` loop), and the condition of an `if`, are both boolean contexts and thus work in exactly the same way.

Both of your assertions are wrong, in that the compiler never checks for either `i < num` or `x < num` in your example, that is not  how `&&` works.

In `for(int i = 0; i < 15 && num; i++)`, the condition is parsed as `(i < 15) && (num != 0)`, which in your example is effectively `(i < 15) && true`, or simply `(i < 15)`.  If you want to check for `(i < num)` then you need to code it that way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15 && i < num; i++)
```

Alternatively:

```
for(int i = 0; i < min(15,num); i++)
```

In `if(x < 15 && num)`, the condition is parsed as `(x < 15) && (num != 0)`, which in your example is effectively `(x < 15) && true`, or simply `(x < 15)`. If you want to check for `(x < num)` then you need to code it that way:

```
if(x < 15 && x < num)
```

Alternatively:

```
if(x < min(15,num))
```

Answer (score 2):

`&& num` doesn't do what you think it does. If you expect it to mean "now take the preceding operation, replace (whatever) with `num` in it and do it again", then no, it is very far from that.

> it checks for both x<15 and x<num

You are mistaken, it doesn't do that. Test for `num == 12, x == 13` to convince yourself. If you want to check for both `x < 15` and `x < num`, just say so:

```
if (x < 15 and x < num)
```

Or you can use `&&`

```
if (x < 15 && x < num)
```

(`&&` and `and` are two spellings for the exact same thing).